# Two identical call stacks differ as they are shown by debugger

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, crash-dumps

In my code I have a bug: I lock `std::mutex` twice.

I always run a debug version of my app.

There are 2 run cases:

1. I run it under the debugger. In this case I get exception with the following stack trace. It is ok.

[image]

2. I just run it without the debugger. I get Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Debug Error window.
   [image]

Then I connect the debugger to the process and click Retry.
I get the following stack trace which is really showing nothing:

[image]

Exactly the same bug. Two different stack traces. Why?

Addition #1: I have all the symbols specified correctly (including Microsoft Windows's one).

Answer (score 0):

In the first stack you are in the application at the place the exception was *raised*. I guess you had set some form of 'break on exception' in debugger.

In the second stack you are in the application at the place the exception was *caught*. This occurs after the raise, in a catch block. Looks like you are in the catch block of the _Call_func frame.

So the two cases look different because they *are* different. Although is the same incident, you are looking at it in different moments.

If I'd venture a guess you have a callback of some sort in which you do not have a try/catch block and let exception propagate to CRT, which dutifully aborts the process because of unhandled exception.

Mandatory reading: [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx) to understand what occurred between the the two momements and how the first stack would transition into the second, if let unwind and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception Dispatching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is causing this behavior:

> When an exception occurs in user-mode code, the system uses the following search order to find an exception handler:
>
> 1. If the process is being debugged, the system notifies the debugger. For more information, see Debugger Exception Handling.
> 2. If the process is not being debugged, or if the associated debugger does not handle the exception, the system attempts to locate a frame-based exception handler by searching the stack frames of the thread in which the exception occurred. The system searches the current stack frame first, then searches through preceding stack frames in reverse order.
> 3. If no frame-based handler can be found, or no frame-based handler handles the exception, but the process is being debugged, the system notifies the debugger a second time.
> 4. If the process is not being debugged, or if the associated debugger does not handle the exception, the system provides default handling based on the exception type. For most exceptions, the default action is to call the ExitProcess function.

In the first example, the debugger stops at 1), in the second example, the system stops at 4) and would usually kill the process. But since you have Visual Studio installed, it thinks you could be a developer and asks you to debug.

Between 1) where the exception is thrown and 4) where the process is about to die, a lot of things happened and the call stack is different.